# Integral of the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$

**My Attempt**

Set $x=a\sin\theta\implies dx=a\cos\theta d\theta$

Thanx @cansomeonehelpmeout for the hint.

$\theta=\sin^{-1}\frac{x}{a}\implies\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\implies|\cos\theta|=\cos\theta$
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}&=\int\frac{a\cos\theta d\theta}{\sqrt{a^2-a^2\sin^2\theta}}=\int\frac{a\cos\theta d\theta}{|a|\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}=\int\frac{a.\cos\theta d\theta}{|a|\sqrt{\cos^2\theta}}\\
&=\int\frac{a.\cos\theta d\theta}{|a|.|\cos\theta|}=\int\frac{a.\cos\theta d\theta}{|a|.\cos\theta}=\begin{cases}\;\:\:\int d\theta=\theta+C \text{ if }a>0\\-\int d\theta= -\theta+C \text{ if }a<0\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases}\;\:\:\sin^{-1}\frac{x}{a}+C  \text{ if }a>0\\-\sin^{-1}\frac{x}{a}+C \text{ if }a<0\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

As the $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\sin^{-1}\frac{x}{a}+C$ is whats given in all references why am I getting this result ?

I can see that the function is independent of the sign of $a$ but why do I seem to get solutions dependent on the sign of $a$ ?

But my doubt is how do I eliminate the negative result while integrating the function ?

**Note:** I undestand $\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\implies \frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}\frac{x}{a}=\frac{1}{a.\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$

Comment: you have a mistake $$\sqrt{a^2 - a^2 \sin^2 \theta} = \vert a \vert \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 \theta}$$

Comment: I think it's common to define $\sin^{-1}(\theta)$ for $\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, which makes $\cos(\theta)\geq 0$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio it'd be helpful to mention why the post is put on hold and what additional information is needed !!!!!!!!

Comment: Actually the reason for which I have closed the question is not lack of context, it is being off-topic. It is a judgement call, but I believe the average quality of MSE questions is miserably dropping, and I am starting to enforce a stricter policy on low-level questions. The $a$-parameter is essentially irrelevant and the primitive of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is $\arcsin(x)$; how to manage substitutions in a one-variable integral is basic knowledge. I believe users with >1k reputation points should not ask this kind of questions.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi i dont think that matters as the original function does not change if $a$ is -ve or +ve.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio i understand the $a$ parameter is irrelevant as its sign does not change the original function, thats entirely not the doubt i mentioned. $\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\implies \frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}\frac{x}{a}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$ which implies $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\sin^{-1}\frac{x}{a}+C$. My doubt was about the term $|\cos\theta|$ which seems to give two solutions while integrating the function and how do I eliminate the negative solution ...

Comment: @ss1729 you're right but the second equality is still wrong because of what i mentioned.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi could u pls explain more ?

Comment: @ss1729 since $\sqrt{a^2 - a^2 \sin^2 \theta} = \vert a \vert \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 \theta}$ and not $a \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 \theta}$, unless you say $a \geq 0$, which i agree with you does not change the polarity of the function if we have $\pm a$

Comment: @AhmadBazzi i mean how this makes the second equality wrong ?

Comment: since you would end up getting $\frac{a}{\vert a \vert } = 1$ if $a \geq 0$ and $-1$ if $a<0$

Comment: @AhmadBazzi $\sqrt{a^2}=a$ Ex. $2^2=(-2)^2=4\implies\sqrt{4}=2$ not $-2$ rather $-\sqrt{4}=-2$. I don't think thats whats eliminating the negative solution.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout thnx. so u mean $x=a\sin\theta\implies\theta=\sin^{-1}\frac{x}{a}\implies\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\implies\cos\theta>0$. right ?. So if I do not consider the principal value branch of $\arcsin$, then the final solution(sign) of the integration also might change right ?

Comment: @ss1729 then if $\sqrt{a^2} = a$, why do you write $\sqrt{\cos^2 \theta} = \vert \cos \theta \vert$ and not $\cos \theta$

Comment: @AhmadBazzi Ok u hv a point. As in practical problems we only need to take the principal square root, ie. a>0. But, i think choosing $a<0$ changes the final solution right ?. And $|\cos\theta|=\cos\theta$ as $\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ modified OP. pls check.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout please check i have modifies OP.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see when there are no bounds to the integral but it might be because of that. Sometimes the change in the bounds in a substitution bring a change in the sign, that might alter the result.

Anyway, here there is a way to integrate it without a substitution (I prefer to avoid them when there are no bounds in the integral, since you can't always verify that it's bijective):

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2 -x^2}} = \frac{1}{|a|}\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}} = \sin^{-1}(x/a) + C$$

Edit: oh no my bad actually you're right it's what you found. Since there is a |a| that appears. The books might just be considering the case a>0 I think